# Binding to DataGridView so each cell is a bound object rather than each row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm trying to set up a DataGridView to represent a page out of a map book.  Each cell in the grid represents a MapGrid object.  Users would use this to set the route for the MapGrids.

```
public class MapGrid
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public short PageNumber { get; set; }
    public char ColumnNumber { get; set; }
    public byte RowNumber { get; set; }
    public RouteSummary Route { get; set; }
}  

public class RouteSummary
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public byte RouteNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering if I can use data binding to bind my list of MapGrid objects to the grid.  I would like to do something like this:

```
List<MapGrid> mapGrids = GetMapGrids();
dataGridView.DataSource = mapGrids;
```

And I would like the dataGridView to display the `MapGrid.RouteSummary.RouteNumber` property.

I was thinking maybe I could create an `ILookup<byte, MapGrid>` to group the MapGrids by row.  Then maybe I could bind that to the DataGridView.  I'm not sure how I would tell it to display the RouteNumber, though.

If the number of columns was constant I could simply create an object with a property for each column and bind a list of those to the DataGridView.  But of course things aren't that simple.  The number of columns is not constant.  So I don't see how that could work.

Any ideas?  Am I trying to do something beyond the scope of data binding?  Right now I'm thinking I'll have to manually populate the DataGridView with my MapGrid objects and use the `CellValueChanged` event to update stuff.

Comment: I'm going to assume data binding just doesn't work like I was hoping.  I've decided to abandon the idea and use a TreeView instead of a DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that what I wanted to do couldn't be done by using the `DataGridView.DataSource` property.  In the end, I used `for` loops to manually add columns and rows to the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with the extra class?  May as well have your MapGrid defined as

```
public class MapGrid
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public short PageNumber { get; set; }
    public char ColumnNumber { get; set; }
    public byte RowNumber { get; set; }
    public int RouteID { get; set; }
    public byte RouteNumber { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use simple binding as you desire.

Comment: The RouteSummary class is actually used elsewhere in the code.  So it's good OO design to break it out.  But, let's say I do go with a single class like you suggested.  How would that help me bind as I was describing?  I don't follow.

Comment: what's the relationship between your objects? is it a one to many between RouteNumber and MapGrid? It's unclear exactly how you want your output to look.  I thought the problem was that you were having difficulty displaying the route number on each map grid row, because it was a property of a RouteSummary object field rather than a property of the MapGrid object.

Comment: Yes, one `Route` can have many `MapGrids`.  The output I'm shooting for is, for example, a `DataGridView` with columns A-F and rows 1-6 (a 6x6 grid, but these numbers are variable, which is what makes it difficult).  I was hoping to set the `DataGridView.DataSource` such that if a `MapGrid` has `ColumnNumber` = 'A' and `RowNumber` = 1 the corresponding cell in the `DataGridView` would display the `MapGrid.Route.RouteNumber`.  Sorry for the delayed response, I didn't notice you replied until just now.