# Binding datagridviewcell to an object C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I need to bind each cell in my datagridview to an object in C#.
Is there anyone how can helps my?

my object looks like -

```
    public DataCellInfo(int row, int col, Color backColor)
    {
        CoordinateCell = new Coordinate(row, col);
        BackColor = backColor;
        IsFill = false;
    }

    public Coordinate CoordinateCell { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsFill { get; set; }
```

I tried to each cell like that -

```
 gameDataView.Rows[row].Cells[col] = new DataCellInfo(row, col, gameDataView[col, row].Style.BackColor);
```

But its seems to be wrong.

Tnx

Comment: I don't think it is possible out of the box. To help you find a solution you will have to desribe your aim a lot more detailed. E.g.: what object, what data source, one-way or two-way binding etc.. As it is the question is too broad and shows no research effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding to DataGridView so each cell is a bound object rather than each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710631/binding-to-datagridview-so-each-cell-is-a-bound-object-rather-than-each-row)

Comment: A DataGrid is primarily row-oriented. Show us what your data looks like (an excerpt should do).

Comment: The class looks as if you only need the DGV to display, not to edit the data, right?

Comment: For now i need to display only. later i will need to read and change the information. for now i just want to bind each cell to new object